# Using object defined in other file without importing

Tags: python

I want to refer to an object in the namespace of the file that imports the one that I am writing.

this is an example:

main.py

```
from imp import *   # main is importing the file I'm writing
...more code...
obj=1               # main defines obj
f()                 # f(), defined in imp, needs to use obj

...more code using obj...
```

This is the file that defines `f()`:

imp.py

```
def f():
 return obj    # I want to refer to main's obj here
```

error on runtime:

```
error: global name 'obj' is not defined
```

How can it be done?
Thanks.

Comment: how would `obj` exist in your function? You define `obj` in main.py

Comment: Yes, cause obj is mostly used in main

Comment: No I am asking how you expect to access  `obj`, are you trying to import from main in imp?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  I think he is trying to define a function that "uses the thing called obj in the namespace where the function is being used".  He doesn't want to import main into imp.   He wants imp to be able to implicitly access the namespace of main, when it is imported there.    IE to define in a different file a function that can behave as if it were written in the same file.  Assuming this is the question he's asking, then the answer is "as neronaut says, it's not a good idea" - so bad in fact that you can't even do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relying on global variables across modules is not really a good idea. You should pass `obj` as a parameter to the function `f()`, like this:

```
f(obj)
```

Then just declare the parameter in the function:

```
def f(obj):
    # code to operate on obj
    return obj
```